# Citrix XenApp Server on Server2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, citrix

I'm trying to install a test server. I've got Server 2008 installed, now I'm trying to install Citrix XenApp 5 on it. 
I downloaded the trial version (which is a 1.1 GB file called XA50_WS2008_EN.zip) and went through the installation. License server (with the 90 day trial license) is correctly installed, mamagement tools are also correctly installed, but it looks like the citrix XenApp server itself has not been installed.

When I start the Citrix Access Management Console locally on the server I get the error "Citrix MFCOM service did not respond as expected. ...".

Windows remote desktop services are configured and working fine. Everything else on the server is working fine.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong, or where to get the server installation from? I'm sure it's a really simple step I missed.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This forum thread on citrix.com contains a solution which may work for you:

[Thread: Citrix MFCOM Service did not respond as expected](http://forums.citrix.com/thread.jspa?threadID=235802&tstart=0)

One post points to several Citrix support articles. In [one](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX112853) of these articles a possible cause is mentioned:

> The Access Management Console in
>   Citrix Presentation Server 4.5
>   leverages MFCOM and CPSCOM interfaces.
>   In order to use a remote Presentation
>   Server in the Access Management
>   Console discovery process, the remote
>   Presentation Server must be enabled
>   for network COM+ access. If the remote
>   Presentation Server is not running
>   Internet Information Services (IIS),
>   then typically network COM+ access is
>   not enabled.

And a resolution:

> Enable network COM+ access. The
>   following describes two methods of
>   enabling network COM+ access.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not the problem here: "COM+ Network Access" is installed (listed under "Role Services"), and under "System Services" I can see that "COM+ Event System" and "COM+ System Application" are running.

Any other ideas? Thanks!

Comment: There are some other links/hints on that forum thread. I hope there is some hint for you.

Answer (score 1):

Run the IMAdmin (-x64) within the "Installation Manager for Windows Server 2008 R2.

http://www.citrix.com/English/ss/downloads/details.asp?downloadId=1863147&productId=186#top

All problems with MFCom are resolved with this.

Answer (score 0):

Check administrative tools: services.  Is the Citrix MFCOM Service installed and running?

Check administrative tools: component services.  Look under component services: computers: my computer: COM+ applications.  Is Citrix IMA COM Interop installed and running?

Answer (score 0):

I remember that XML service always gave me troubles on XenApp 5. YOu need to use command line CTXXMLSS tool to register the XML service, restart the server and you will be good to go. Hope this helps.